# Send data from web page form to a self hosted api

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a self owin self hosted API, and a simple html site, which I want to submit form data from to the self hosted API. I am just currently testing the webapi on localhost, and the site is being hosted on localhost as well via IIS. I was not sure what I needed to change in the html or C# code to make this work. Here is the basics of what I have:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public TestController() {}

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult() 
    {
        //do stuff
        return OK();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //POST localhost:9400/api/Test
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]FormDatacollection name) 
    {
        //do stuff
        return OK();
    }
}
```

And here is a very simple html for the site:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My Test Page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="localhost:9400/api/test" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I want the text that is put into the textbox on the website to be sent over to the self hosted api via post. I tried it with what I have, but it never got to the post, and it appears as if the request was never sent out from the browser. However, if I manually type in localhost:9400/api/Test in the browser, the Get is reached, and I get the OK response back.

I just have the basic configuration for the web api.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuiler) 
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Is what I want to do possible, and if so how can I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work without some changes, your rest api is expecting the data to be sent in as json. Firstly I strongly recommend getting a copy of [Fiddler](https://www.google.de/urlhttps://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.telerik.com/fiddler&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwismZWA_PDHAhXLwBQKHUHvALw&usg=AFQjCNGY5eqyh8uRUDSYsPDDbTNL4aUgVw&sig2=rIY4GaxSc67iZ7CMRMRjxA) then you'll see exactly what's coming from your site and back from your service. You're probably finding that you can't debug in your service because what the service is receiving doesn't match any of the signatures in your controller so the framework itself is dealing with the invalid request. The framework will match requests with methods based on the http verb and method parameters.

In terms of getting it working, do a search for sending HTML form data to a rest API, lots of results on this site and elsewhere.